# Using an HTML actionlink to sort a list

Tags: html, model-view-controller, view, controller, actionlink

I have a list of possible entries stored in a database. I sort and display these entries into a new view depending on an entry put into a textbox, or from clicking on an html actionlink. The main idea of this can be seen below.

```
    public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString, int? sortType)
    {

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            if (sortType == 1)
            {
                //Sort the results strictly based on the HTML header options
                applications = applications.Where(s => s.Business.Equals(searchString));
            }
            else
            {
                //sort based on the input of the form
                applications = applications.Where(s => s.Business.Contains(searchString)
                                           || s.ApName.Contains(searchString));
            }
        }

        return View(applications.ToList());
    }
```

The first part of this if statement is activated by clicking a link like so,

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("CITY", "index", "app", new {SearchString = "city", sortType=1}, null)</li>
```

Although my code is working, I'm just wondering if there is a more "proper" way of doing what I coded, without having to pass a sortType variable to determine whether to sort based on the form or the actionlink. I'm sure what I have done is quite a bad way of doing it, but I'm very new to this.

Comment: Might be better suited to CodeReview http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ You may get a better response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are after because your question keeps talking about sorting but your code is talking about filtering.  You could try to specify default values so the Where statements short-circuit when those criteria are not populated. Ex:

```
public ActionResult Index(string city = null, string business = null){
    var model = applications
        .Where(x => city == null || x.City.Contains(city))
        .Where(x => business == null || x.Business == business);

    return View(model);
}
```